# Doxygen: Add input-directories using wildcards

Tags: doxygen

I am using Doxygen 1.8.6 on a Windows machine and try to add input-directories using wildcards.

I have a directory with several sub-directories containing source-code but I only want to add specific directories. In the following example, I only want to let Doxygen parse the subdirectories starting with the string 'own_'.

Currently I am adding each directory separately but this is very inconvenient as the version can change or even the contained modules/libraries (the directory-content is generated by another program).

```
modules\
        lib_x\
        mod_ab\
        ext_mod_ab\
        ext_lib_cde\
        own_module_foo_1v1\
        own_module_bar_2v0\
        own_library_foo_1v0\
        own_library_bar_1v0\
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use

```
@include {filename}
```

within the doxyfile. The referenced file has to be generated using scripts. 
My doxyfile looks like this

```
INPUT     = .
@INCLUDE  = temp_path_file
```

The required command-scipt to get all matching directories looks like this under Windows (masking, e.g. path1_*, works as well):

```
for /d %%a in ("%USER_PATH%\*") do echo INPUT += %%~fa >> %FILE_NAME%
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working anymore as of February 2023.

Comment: To keep my previous comment focused on the question that was actually asked: this answer does not seem correct to me because the person who posted the answer specifically said: "I only want to add specific directories". That is also my use case and this accepted answer is not working for me. The line `INPUT = .` searches all directories (assuming you have Doxygen's recursive flag set).

Answer (score 0):

Use a batch script to create your doxygen manual. Append your doxygen Manual with lines:

```
INPUT += %directory%
```

via the Windows Shell command `echo`. You can filter your directories by names there and add only specific Folders.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you right. Doxygen is already called out of some batch-script. I have added the line as mentioned and tried to set the batch-variable but doxygen is not able to resolve the variable and shows "Warning: tag INPUT: input source `%directory%' does not exist"

Comment: use the batch script to add line to the manual. e.g:  `echo "INPUT += %Directory%" >> Doxygen.manual`

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use Doxygen's support for expanding environment variables:

```
INPUT = $(SPACE_SEPARATED_LIST)
```

As the example variable name implies, the value of the variable needs to be a space-separated list of file or directory names.

Of course you will need to export the `SPACE_SEPARATED_lIST` variable so that Doxygen is aware of it.

The accepted answer did not work for me as of February 2023. I'm running Doxygen 1.9.6 on a Debian-based OS. The accepted answer says to do this:

```
INPUT     = .
@INCLUDE  = temp_path_file
```

Doxygen seems to still search all directories due to the `INPUT = .` line.

Comment: Which version of doxygen did you use and on which OS. You wrote: "This doesn't seem to be working anymore as of February 2023", what didn't work please show procedure you used.

Comment: Doxygen will take the last setting of a setting it sees. In the accepted answer first the `INPUT` is set to `.` (and this will result in the fact tat the files from the current directory are used and when `RECURSIVE` is set also the files of the underlying directories), With the `@INCLUDE ...` there are just some elements added (`+=`) to the `INPUT`, so the solution here would be either for the first setting in the generated file not to use the `+=` or to add on top of the generated file set `INPUT=` or remove `INPUT=.` from the original file. Best is the setting of `INPUT=`

Comment: I also tried variations of `INPUT = @INCLUDE <filename>` and `INPUT = @INCLUDE = <filename>` and so on. None of them worked. This usage of `@INCLUDE` is not documented in the Doxygen docs site. If you have a working setup with `@INCLUDE` maybe you can just add an answer to this question? Going back-and-forth in these comments is kinda inefficient...

Comment: `@INCLUDE` is just like an `#include` in e.g. C. The usage of `@INCLUDE` is documented in the chapter Configuration of the documentation, see e.g. https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html

Answer (score 0):

Small example (as requested by @KayceBasques in comment in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75495328/1657886)

**Doxyfile**

```
INPUT = .
QUIET = YES
@INCLUDE my_incl
```

**my_incl**

```
INPUT = 
INPUT += my_first_dir
INPUT += my_second_dir
```