# Doxygen search source files which match nested folder pattern

Tags: filter, doxygen, glob, subdirectory

i want to use doxygen to search through nested folders which contain .c and .h files. so i tried giving to the `INPUT` tag the following:

```
INPUT = $(WORKSPACE_DIR)../../*/test/*
```

so basically doxygen shall search my root project directory and filter and generate only the documentation only for source files which are in nested subfolders which match the given name e.g. "test"

i found this

[Doxygen: Add input-directories using wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743233/doxygen-add-input-directories-using-wildcards)

which says

> The referenced file has to be generated using scripts

i tried in my doxyfile the following:

```
for /d %%a in ("..\..\test\") do echo INPUT += %%~fa >> %FILE_NAME%
```

but this just gives nothing empty result in html folder i'm not familiar with the batch syntax

```
doxygen version: 1.8.18 (a1b07ad0e92e4526c9ba1711d39f06b58c2a7459)
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.h
RECURSIVE              = YES
for /d %%a in ("..\..\test\") do echo INPUT += %%~fa >> %FILE_NAME%
```

i have folder structures similar to this:

```
root\
        test\subfoler_1\a.c
        subfolder\test\subfolder\b.c , b.h
        test\subfolder_1\subfolder_2\ f.c , f.h
        ..........
```

ok i played a little around with the commands in my test batch and now at least i see some output:

```
For /R C:\workspace\root\ %%a IN (*.c,*.h) do echo INPUT += %%~fa
```

with this i see in the command line the files printed. problem now still remains to just "catch" or print the files located in `"test"` and ignore everything else

once i have this next step would be to copy paste the findings in the doxyfile for the `INPUT` tag

Comment: i would also like to add i need something which goes through the entire nested folder structure and looks for matches with this "test" name because in the workspace two folders above these "test" folders have all different depths of nested folder structures

Comment: to further explain the second comment i would need something which discovers source files in these also:  test\subfolder_1\subolder_2\src   or test\subfolder_1\subfolder_2\subfolder_3

Comment: What is in `$(WORKSPACE_DIR)` ? Which version of doxygen? Doxygen does not understand the (first) `*` as this is not supported for `INPUT`. The last `*` is probably not necessary when setting `RECURSIVE=YES`. What is the problem with the batch command? without the error message we cannot advise here.

Comment: hello doxygen version: 1.8.18 (a1b07ad0e92e4526c9ba1711d39f06b58c2a7459), $(WORKSPACE_DIR) is the path where the batch file is executed or lets say located and two folders above is my root project, i now tried this: for /d %%a in ("..\..\test\") do echo INPUT += %%~fa >> %FILE_NAME% but still empty result, so not really an error but it didnt processed anything, RECURSIVE i have already set to YES

Comment: Does `$(WORKSPACE_DIR)` have a slash or backslash at the end? What happens when you do `dir ..\..\*\test\*` probably something like "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." as DOS doesn't lik ethe `*` either. Mybe something like `dir /b /s ..\..\test` gives some results (don't know how to do this in the for loop though, maybe /d/r). Where did you specify the for loop (in the Doxyfile??)